# Firebase Crashlytics error logs in samsung phone

Tags: java, android, firebase, crashlytics

I have uploaded a signed app on the play store. and today when I opened my firebase pannel in crashlytics it's showing 2 crashes in the last 24 hours. Both the crashes were on the same java class and line and also both on the Samsung phone only.

Here is the error:  Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE flg=0x4200010....

It's in my receiver class: below is the code for the same

```
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivityManager != null) {
            networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {

                if (alertdialog != null) {
                    alertdialog.dismiss();
                }
            } else {

                builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.internet_dialouge, null);
                builder.setView(view);
                builder.create();
                builder.setCancelable(true);
                alertdialog = builder.show();
                view.findViewById(R.id.btnDismiss)
                        .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                alertdialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                view.findViewById(R.id.btnSetting)
                        .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                context.startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS));
                            }
                        });}}}}
```

Crashlytics showing error in this line: alertdialog = builder.show();

And I use this receiver class in the main activity like this:

```
myReceiver = new MyReceiver();
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
        myReceiver = new MyReceiver();
        registerReceiver(myReceiver, intentFilter);
```

I am not understanding why this error in crashlytics.

Answer (score 0):

"context" may be not initialized when your application reaches the line

> builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

Please check context is always initialized. You can check like this.

> if(context!=null) {
> //build alertdialog. }